# Editing .htaccess for php files and url as hostname

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need to rewrite all php files to my index.html (already done) But also need that if someone writess http://192.168.X.X/moodle rewrite to another moodle page. (Only for IP)

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ index.html

# This one is bad because I only want to work with de IP...
# RewriteRule ^moodle$ http://moodle.mywebsite.net

# This code doesn't works...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^192.168.30.143 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://moodle.mywebsite.net/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule for detecting `192.168.` IPs and redirecting them:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.
RewriteRule ^moodle(/.*)?$ http://moodle.mywebsite.net$1 [L,R=301]
```